# Dropdown with input field

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using `react-bootstrap` for adding `bootstrap` elements to my application. I need to add a dropdown-button that has a list of "labels" that the user can use to tag their items with.

My problem is with adding an input field so that they can add a "custom" label. Here's how it looks currently (blue squares are checkboxes):

[image]

First I tried:

```
<Dropdown id="myDropdown">
    <Dropdown.Toggle bsStyle="warning">Label as...</Dropdown.Toggle>
    <Dropdown.Menu>
        <li onSelect={...}>
            <Checkbox onClick={...} checked={...} inline>Some label</Checkbox>
        </li>
        <li onSelect={...}>
            <Checkbox onClick={...} checked={...} inline>Some other label</Checkbox>
        </li>
        <li><input /></li>
    </Dropdown.Menu>
</Dropdown>
```

However, this closes the `dropdown` when you click on the `input` element.

So I tried implementing a slight variation to an example shown in the official documentation (search for "[**Custom Dropdown Components**](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/)" and view code). This allows me to click and type in the `input`, but now the dropdown doesn't close when I click outside the element.

---

**TL;DR**

How can I achieve a dropdown that allows me to click an `input` field that also closes when you click outside the menu?

**EDIT:**

Adding generated html for my second implementation:

```
<div class="dropdown btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i><!-- react-text: 153 --> <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 154 -->Label as...<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 155 --> <!-- /react-text --><span class="caret"></span></button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="on"><span></span><!-- react-text: 162 --> Some label<!-- /react-text --></label></li>
     <li><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="on"><span></span><!-- react-text: 167 --> Some other label<!-- /react-text --></label></li>
     <li><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="on"><span></span><input type="text" value="" style="height: 17px;font-size: .9em;"></label></li>
     <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
     <li role="presentation" class=""><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Clear labels</a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: Could you paste in what the compiled HTML turns out to be?

Comment: @JoshuaTerrill, sure thing. For which of the two implementations I tried though?

Comment: The second one, where you can click in it and type in the input, but the dropdown doesn't close.

Comment: @JoshuaTerrill, yeah just added it. :)

Comment: One thing that I'm noticing that is not being added in the compiled version is the attribute `data-toggle="dropdown"` to the button. So it should be `<button type="button" class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-warning" data-toggle="dropdown">`. Maybe that's a clue into why it's not working?

Comment: I made a fiddle with the regular versions of bootstrap (not react versions) and once I added that `data-toggle` attribute it worked. https://jsfiddle.net/v7gk7e76/ not sure about the react version. If you can get some sort of working snippet running on a fiddle or plunkr running react, I can try to help more.

Comment: @JoshuaTerrill Thanks, I'll try this out and let you know in a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the answer a few days ago, and I'll post it here in case someone stumbles upon this post in the future.

You need to install `react-overlays` and import `ReactRootWrapper`. Modifying the sample code (from the [Custom Dropdown Component](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/) in the docs), the component should now look something like:

```
<RootCloseWrapper onRootClose={this.setOpenStateToFalse}>
  <Dropdown id="dropdown-custom-menu" open={this.state.open} onToggle={this.toggleOpenState}>
    <CustomToggle bsRole="toggle">Custom toggle</CustomToggle>
    <CustomMenu bsRole="menu">
      <MenuItem eventKey="1">Red</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem eventKey="2">Blue</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem eventKey="3" active>Orange</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem eventKey="1">Red-Orange</MenuItem>
    </CustomMenu>
  </Dropdown>
</RootCloseWrapper>
```

I haven't added the functions in the example, but their name explains what they do. Basically `setOpenStateToFalse()` needs to always set `this.state.open` to `false`, and `toggleOpenState()` needs to invert the current boolean value of `this.state.open`.

Hope someone finds this useful.

Comment: I dont see input inside menu.

Comment: RootCloseWrapper seems to be gone from react-overlays